# Swift 4 - Unable to control UIButton size when added to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar, xcode9, swift4

I have been trying to build a custom UINavigationBar, but my button.frame inputs haven't had any effect.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "I_sent"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action), for: .touchUpInside)

    // This doesn't seem to have an effect:
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
}

@objc func action() {
    print("Action")
}
```

The code (above) appears like this when run:

[image]

But I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add constraints to the `UIButton` as:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.frame.size.width).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.frame.size.height).isActive = true
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Jake Happy Coding :-)